# DateDiff Function

Tags: sqlplus, datediff

I am trying some [examples for DateDiff Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

This statement gives me an error From keyword not found where expected.
Why do I get this error and how can I solve it?
Also, when I try this :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,datebegin,datestop) 
From table;
```

I get this error `"datediff" invalid identifier`. 
How can I get day difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What database are you using?

A google search gave me this:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2508/sql-server-datediff-example/

DAY     SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,'09/23/2011 15:00:00','08/02/2011 14:00:00')

where 'DD' is used as opposed to 'days'.

Try answering these question:

What database I'm using?

Is the database case sensitive? This might be the error occurring with the datediff as oppose to DATEDIFF

Comment: Yup, "What database I'm using?" this helped me. THANKS! I was using wrong syntax.

Comment: @lilu i know its a small thing, but I too asked something very similar..maybe u didnt see mine?

Answer (score 0):

try `SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,datebegin,datestop) from table`

I think 'day' also works, I was able to execute:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'1/1/2011','1/1/2012')
```

So Im not sure what you're doing wrong.. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I already tried this and it gives me the same error : invalid indentifier

Comment: @lilu can you execute this:
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'1/1/2011','1/1/2012')

This worked for me.. I get 365